# How can I paste a element between all elements of a list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to paste between every element of a lista special element. In example:

```
(EINFUEGEN '(A B C) '*);-> (A * B * C)
```

How can I implement that on the easiest way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fun way:

```
(cdr (mapcan #'list '#1=(* . #1#) '(a b c)))
```

The respectable way:

```
(loop
   for (x . xs) on '(a b c) 
   collect x
   when xs collect '*)
```

- `for <var> on <list>` iterates over all sublists, meaning `var` will be bound to `(a b c)`, then `(b c)` then `(c)` and finally `()`.
- `(x . xs)` is a *destructuring* notation to bind respectively `x` and `xs` to the head and tail of each list being visited. This is necessary here to check whether there are remaining elements.
- `collect <val>` adds `<val>` to implicit collection being built
- `when <test> <clause>` executes the LOOP clause `<clause>` only when `<test>` is satisfied. Here, I test if there are more elements in the list; when it is the case, I also collect the star symbol.

Comment: You helped me three times this week is there a way that I can chat with you directly ^^

Comment: Really brilliant solution!

Comment: Could you explain me the elements of the loop, please?

Comment: (1) I don't use it much but I heard there is a chat over here. I tend to answer questions when I have time (or when I procrastinate :-/ ) so generally I am better at replying asynchronously.   Do you have something urgent to ask? (2) Loop: I can't explain it better than http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html The whole book is great and free to read online.